# unable to login in NiFi when integrated with LDAP

Tags: hadoop, ldap, apache-nifi

I have generated certificates for Initial Admin Identity using tls toolkit and secured my standalone NiFi node. I am able to login with Initial Admin Identity via client certificates. I have also created my LDAP users in NiFi and given them permissions to view and modify NiFi UI using Initial Admin Identity user.

But when I am trying to login with my LDAP users, I am getting `unable to login` in NiFi UI.

**LDAP Configuration:**

```
<provider>
    <identifier>ldap-provider</identifier>
    <class>org.apache.nifi.ldap.LdapProvider</class>
    <property name="Authentication Strategy">SIMPLE</property>
    <property name="Manager DN">cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org</property>
    <property name="Manager Password">admin</property>
    <property name="Referral Strategy">IGNORE</property>
    <property name="Connect Timeout">10 secs</property>
    <property name="Read Timeout">10 secs</property>
    <property name="Url">ldap://192.168.99.100</property>
    <property name="User Search Base">dc=example,dc=org</property>
    <property name="User Search Filter">cn={0}</property>
    <property name="Authentication Expiration">12 hours</property>
 </provider>
```

There is no information present in app and users NiFi logs related to unable to login issue.

Can someone suggest where things are going wrong & why am I getting unable to login in NiFi UI? How can we successfully login in NiFi with LDAP as authentication provider?